Do I need a markov switching model or an error correction model?
I am running a lagged time series regression on petrol price data. The petrol prices have a 14 day cycle where prices steadily decrease for 13 days and then shoot back up on the 14th day. This is constant throughout the period. Underlying this is movements in the price of oil and taxes that are captured in the variable cost_t.
I want to model how prices would change with the increase to taxes, but fitting a simple lagged model would not work as there are two regimes: cutting and spiking.
When I run the lagged regression the coefficient is about 0.75 on price (t-1) and 0.25 on cost (t). Clearly the coefficients would not be appropriate to model the relationship in the price spiking period.
Given I know perfectly when the two regimes are, do I need to run a markov switching model? Are these models only used when the timing of regime changes are unknown? If not, do I run an error correction model instead? Or any other alternative
Thanks!
